# How is VMware based on UNIX?

Tags: vmware

I am studying a course of Operating Systems, and I have just read the [textbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0985673524) saying that

> UNIX became the basis for Apple's MacOS X, Linux, VMware, and Google Android.

What? ... It surprised me because this sentence tells me that VMware (a virtualization tool) is based on UNIX (an operating system).

Could someone help me understand how we can say VMware is based on UNIX?

Comment: I think they're talking about VMware's ESXi, a hypervisor. See this article: [“It’s a Unix system, I know this!”](http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2013/06/its-a-unix-system-i-know-this.html)

Comment: this article will explain a bit more also:  http://www.v-front.de/2013/08/a-myth-busted-and-faq-esxi-is-not-based.html

Answer (score 10):

[VMware's ESXi](https://www.vmware.com/products/esxi-and-esx/overview) is apparently based on the [linux kernel](https://www.kernel.org/). There is a [lawsuit](https://sfconservancy.org/linux-compliance/vmware-lawsuit-faq.html) about this because the linux kernel is under [GPL v2](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html).

Here is a comparison between a system using a complete linux kernel and a system with VMware ESXi.

[image]
*(Figure under [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) by [Software Freedom Conservancy](https://sfconservancy.org/))*

Read the following FAQ for full details:
[Frequently Asked Questions about Christoph Hellwig's VMware Lawsuit](https://sfconservancy.org/linux-compliance/vmware-lawsuit-faq.html)

**== Update==**

The lawsuit has concluded see:

- [VMware Suit Concludes in Germany](https://sfconservancy.org/news/2019/apr/02/vmware-no-appeal/)
- [VMware’s Update to Mr. Hellwig’s Legal Proceedings](https://news.vmware.com/company/march-2019-hellwig-legal-proceedings)